# Array List .get() not working correctly

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm implementing a greedy algorithm to solve the knapsack problem, and I keep running into this issue that I can't figure out.

```
public void greedySort() {
   int curW = 0;
   Collections.sort(sorted);
   for(int i = 0; i < sorted.size(); i++) {
      Entry temp = sorted.get(i);
      System.out.println("Index: " + temp.index + "Ratio: " + temp.ratio);
   }
   System.out.println("Sorted size: "+sorted.size());
   while(sorted.size() > 0 && curW < maxW) {
      Entry temp = sorted.get(0);
      if(curW + temp.weight <= maxW) {
         ret.add(temp);
         curW += temp.weight;
      }
      sorted.remove(0);
   }
}
```

When I run the

```
Entry temp = sorted.get(0);
```

I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException, even though the for loop after the Collections.sort(sorted) will iterate through "sorted" correctly and print out all the values in the right order. What am I doing wrong? Also, if you see any errors with my algorithm design within this code, also let me know about those.

Edit: Added the Sorted.size println. It prints 20, as it should. Sorted is an ArrayList of knapsack entries sorted by their value/weight ratio. Sorted is NOT empty, here is the output after running a 20 value input file through it

```
Index: 14 Ratio: 14.0
Index: 0 Ratio: 3.1379310344827585
Index: 15 Ratio: 2.7
Index: 4 Ratio: 1.7555555555555555
Index: 17 Ratio: 1.72
Index: 19 Ratio: 1.4210526315789473
Index: 8 Ratio: 1.3333333333333333
Index: 18 Ratio: 1.2195121951219512
Index: 11 Ratio: 1.2
Index: 1 Ratio: 0.9230769230769231
Index: 9 Ratio: 0.9230769230769231
Index: 6 Ratio: 0.8636363636363636
Index: 2 Ratio: 0.8591549295774648
Index: 12 Ratio: 0.6530612244897959
Index: 5 Ratio: 0.647887323943662
Index: 16 Ratio: 0.6111111111111112
Index: 7 Ratio: 0.5876288659793815
Index: 10 Ratio: 0.3508771929824561
Index: 13 Ratio: 0.34831460674157305
Index: 3 Ratio: 0.15
Sorted size: 20
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Sorted is created here using values given to the function by a driver

```
public void Greedy(int[] val, int[] weight, int maxVal) {
  final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  GreedyAlgorithm alg = new GreedyAlgorithm();
  alg.sorted = new ArrayList<Entry>();
  alg.ret = new ArrayList<Entry>();
  alg.maxW = maxVal;
  for(int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
     Entry newE = new Entry();
     newE.index = i;
     newE.value = val[i];
     newE.weight = weight[i];
     newE.ratio = ((double)newE.value)/((double)newE.weight);
     alg.sorted.add(newE);
  }
  alg.greedySort();
  final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) );
}
```

Comment: You keep removing the first element in the loop. That probably leaves the list empty at one point.

Comment: not know your algorithm, but add `&& sorted.size() > 0` to while loop check.

Comment: If `sorted.get(0)` throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, then it's pretty certain that `sorted` is empty.

Comment: You really need to show us how `sorted` is being created.

Comment: Change your loop to `while (sorted.size() > 0 && curW < maxW)`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my IDE was causing some kind of issue, it has recently been somewhat unstable. After restarting it, I opened the files and ran them, and the error was gone.

Thanks to Thilo and hungryghost, that while loop issue would have come up after restarting either way.

Answer (score 0):

As previous commenter pointed out, you keep removing the first element in your ArrayList. By the time you iterate through all 20 elements, you have removed everything in your ArrayList.

So just make sure you end your loop when the list is empty. Change your while condition to this:

```
while(sorted.size() > 0 && curW < maxW) {
    // Put this print line inside the loop to debug.
    System.out.println("Sorted size: "+sorted.size());
    Entry temp = sorted.get(0);
    if(curW + temp.weight <= maxW) {
        ret.add(temp);
        curW += temp.weight;
    }
    sorted.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: Recompiled and tried with this addition, nothing changed. This will help once the code finally does execute.

Comment: To debug, add a println inside the while loop to show the sorted.size(). Sorted is definitely getting emptied out. That's what the exception is.